# Git working on bash but not working on VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Previously everything was working fine, at some point Git started to behave strangely on VSCode.

I can Stage the code, but most of the other functions are not working. Per example if I ask to commit, I have the following on the console . Same with pull and push . But if I use Git with commands in the console it's working perfectly.

```
2023-03-24 22:52:04.641 [info] Log level: Info
2023-03-24 22:52:04.641 [info] Validating found git in: "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"
2023-03-24 22:52:04.641 [info] Using git "2.40.0.windows.1" from "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"
2023-03-24 22:52:04.712 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [72ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:04.859 [info] > git rev-parse --git-dir --git-common-dir [80ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:04.873 [info] Open repository: c:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react
2023-03-24 22:52:04.949 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [67ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:04.971 [info] > git config --get commit.template [64ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:04.988 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [67ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.012 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [56ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.076 [info] > git status -z -uall [80ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.086 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [68ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.143 [info] > git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%D%n%B -z -n184 -- c:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\index.html [70ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.175 [info] > git config --get commit.template [74ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.177 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [67ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.184 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [93ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.243 [info] > git status -z -uall [59ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.442 [info] > git rev-list --count 2174a3a7f2d7bfe11614905b59a2e929e358b438.. -- c:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\index.html [57ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.519 [info] > git log --format=%H%n%aN%n%aE%n%at%n%ct%n%P%n%D%n%B -z -n7 -- c:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\index.html [69ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.549 [info] > git check-ignore -v -z --stdin [55ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.707 [info] > git show --textconv :index.html [65ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.715 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\index.html [64ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:05.774 [info] > git cat-file -s 1290a2cbf506e5218326298008f4567bd76cade7 [52ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:07.927 [info] > git check-ignore -v -z --stdin [50ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:13.417 [info] > git add -A -- C:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\.github\workflows\install_dependencies.yml C:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\index.html C:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\src\doc\Doc [65ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:13.473 [info] > git config --get commit.template [49ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:13.480 [info] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track)%00%(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master [50ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:13.540 [info] > git status -z -uall [54ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:14.657 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\index.html [50ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:14.711 [info] > git cat-file -s 899fc10ccd507b744402ac3f3499effbdf6224d9 [49ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:14.770 [info] > git show --textconv :index.html [51ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:15.614 [info] > git show --textconv :.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG [52ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:15.620 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG [52ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:15.934 [info] > git check-ignore -v -z --stdin [52ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:16.441 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\index.html [51ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:16.448 [info] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\costa\Documents\KiteMeUp-react\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG [49ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:16.494 [info] > git cat-file -s 899fc10ccd507b744402ac3f3499effbdf6224d9 [48ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:16.504 [info] > git show --textconv :.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG [48ms]
2023-03-24 22:52:16.553 [info] > git show --textconv :index.html [51ms]
```

Comment: Please reword your question, and describe what doesn't work. e.g : what actions do you do in vscode ? go through the GUI ? Type commands in the integrated terminal?

Comment: The log you pasted isn't relevant, you can delete it from your question -- nothing indicates an error there, and vscode does run a whole set of git commands in order to follow the status of your files in the repo. At best, it shows that no commit/push/pull was performed.